# How to work with events whose probability is random?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, poisson-process

I am having some problems working with stochastic processes/random variables whose probabilities are themselves random. In particular I am not really sure which "operations" are allowed and how to think of them.

For instance, suppose $A,B$ are two events, but suppose that $P(A)=X_A$ and $P(B)=X_B$ where the $X_i$ themselves are random variables. Now, if I wanted to compute $P(A\cap B)$ I would probably want to use itterated expectation. But its not really clear to me how to do this. I mean $P(A\cap B)$ should be a random variable, but $E[P(A\cap B|\mathcal{F})]$ isn't right? So something goes wrong here and it appears this doesn't work, at least not in a totally straight-forward manner. Is there any way around this?

A more sophisticated example would be a Poisson Process where the intensity itself is random. I.e. suppose $N(\cdot)$ is a Poisson Process with intensity $\lambda$. Now assume that Poisson Process is "thinned doubly randomly". That is, we keep each point $i$ of the process with probability $X_i$, which itself is a random variable on $(0,1)$. Denote the thinned process by $M(\cdot)$. Now, to characterize this process, I want to compute $P(M(A)=k)$ for some borel set $A$. How is this probability interpreted? Is it a random variable, and if yes, can we write:
\begin{equation}
P(M(A)=k)=\frac{e^{-\lambda X}(\lambda X)^k}{k!}?
\end{equation} 
Moreover, if this is the case, how do I compute this?

Also, I haven't found much on the topic in my standard probability references. If anyone has good literature on this, it would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: In the first case, you would write $P(A\mid\mathcal X)=X_A$ for every event $A$, where $\mathcal X$ denotes the sigma-algebra geneated by all the random variables $X_A$, hence, by the tower property, $P(A)=E(P(A\mid\mathcal X))=E(X_A)$ but there is no way to deduce $P(A\cap B\mid\mathcal X)$ or $P(A\cap B)$ from this information only.

Comment: In the second case, conditionally on $\mathcal X$, each $M(A)$ is Poisson with parameter $$\Lambda_A=\lambda\int_AX_xdx$$ in particular, $$P(M(A)=k\mid\mathcal X)=e^{-\Lambda_A}\frac{(\Lambda_A)^k}{k!}$$ and $$P(M(A)=k)=E(P(M(A)=k\mid\mathcal X))=\frac1{k!}E(e^{-\Lambda_A}(\Lambda_A)^k)$$ has no general convenient form, but $$E(M(A))=E(\Lambda_A)=\lambda\int_AE(X_x)dx$$

Comment: I am a bit confused regarding your first comment @Did. You establish $P(A)=E[P(A|\chi)]=E(X_A) \in \mathbb{R}$. But $P(A)=X_A$ which is a random variable by assumption. Isn't the probability itself still random?

The second case is clear, thanks!

Comment: Please read again: $P(A)$ is a number, $P(A\mid\mathcal X)$ is a random variable, and $X_A=P(A\mid\mathcal X)$.

Comment: So what you are saying is that to define $P(A)=X_A$ is invalid/abuse of notation? The correct definition of a "random probability" would be to make it random conditioned on $\sigma(X_A)$?

Comment: @Did After thinking further on it, I think I have understood what I wanted to know from your comments. If you feel like pasting them into an answer, I will accept it. Thanks for your time.